# How to round up last digit in two decimal point using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, decimal

I want to round up last digit of two decimal point if last digit more then 5.

For example,
  2.58 to 2.60

Besides that, I also want to round down last digit of two decimal point if last digit less then 5.

For example, 6.54 to 6.50

How to do this by using javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by Math.round and then dividing the result by 10 (which results in an extra 0 in a floating point number:

```
let number = 2.58;
let rounded = Math.round(number * 10, 2) / 10; // 2.60

let number2 = 2.54;
let rounded2 = Math.round(number2 * 10, 2) / 10; // 2.50
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the toFixed() method.

```
var number = 2.58;
var rounded = number.toFixed(1);
console.log(parseFloat(rounded).toFixed(2));
```